# Writing a double sum in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to StackOverflow, and I am extremely new to Python.

My problem is this... I am needing to write a double-sum, as follows:

[image: equation]

The motivation is that this is the angular correction to the gravitational potential used for the geoid.

1. I am having difficulty writing the sums.  And please, before you say "Go to such-and-such a resource," or get impatient with me, this is the first time I have ever done coding/programming/whatever this is.
2. Is this a good place to use a "for" loop?
3. I have data for the two indices `(n,m)` and for the coefficients `c_{nm}` and `s_{nm}` in a .txt file.  Each of those items is a column.  When I say `usecols`, do I number them `0` through `3`, or `1` through `4`?

---

(the equation above)

```
\begin{equation}
V(r, \phi, \lambda) = \sum_{n=2}^{360}\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^{n}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left[c_{nm}*\cos{(m\lambda)} + s_{nm}*\sin{(m\lambda)}\right]*\sqrt{\frac{(n-m)!}{(n+m)!}(2n + 1)(2 - \delta_{m0})}P_{nm}(\sin{\lambda})
\end{equation}
```

Comment: ...where do you say "usecols"? You should break this problem into manageable steps and tackle them one by one: to start, open and parse file to import data. If you have already done some of this, where is your code? In general, though, summing over multiple values *is* a good bet for e.g. `for n in range(2, 361):`.

Comment: A sum is simply a `for` loop whose body adds the result of a calculation to a variable.

Comment: likewise, a nested sum is made of such for loops nested

Comment: I'll wait for more details before trying to answer, but a generator expression along with [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum) is likely to be more suited to this problem than a `for` loop in Python.

Comment: Any indexing in python starts at 0, so for usecols, that would be `usecols=[0,1,2,3]`

Comment: @jon, `usecols` is a kwarg for `numpy.genfromtxt`, hence the added label.

Comment: @jpmc26, I am not sure what other details I should add, but I don't know enough about this to know what a "generator expression" is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, if I had any relevant code for this, I would have included it.  Like I said, I have next to no clue about what I'm doing.

Comment: @Barmar, okay that makes sense, but what kind of syntax do I use to implement such a thing?

Comment: @askewchan, thank you for answering my usecols question.  That's one thing checked off the list!  :)

Answer (score 4):

(2) Yes, a "for" loop is fine. As @jpmc26 notes, a generator expression is a good alternative to a "for" loop. IMO, you'll want to use numpy if efficiency is important to you.

(3) As @askewchan notes, "usecols" refers to an argument of [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html); as specified in that documentation, column indexes start at 0, so you'll want to use 0 to 3.

A naive implementation might be okay since the larger factorial is the denominator, but I wouldn't be surprised if you run into numerical issues. Here's something to get you started. Note that you'll need to define `P()` and `a`. I don't understand how "0 through 3" relates to c and s since their indexes range much further. I'm going to assume that each (and delta) has its own file of values.

```
import math
import numpy
c = numpy.getfromtxt("the_c_file.txt")
s = numpy.getfromtxt("the_s_file.txt")
delta = numpy.getfromtxt("the_delta_file.txt")
def V(r, phi, lam):
  ret = 0
  for n in xrange(2, 361):
    for m in xrange(0, n + 1):
      inner = c[n,m]*math.cos(m*lam) + s[n,m]*math.sin(m*lam)
      inner *= math.sqrt(math.factorial(n-m)/math.factorial(n+m)*(2*n+1)*(2-delta[m,0]))
      inner *= P(n, m, math.sin(lam))
    ret += math.pow(a/r, n) * inner
  return ret
```

Make sure to write [unittests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) to check the math. Note that "lambda" is a reserved word.

Comment: thank you so much!  This gives me a great running start!  I'll see how it goes.  :)  I appreciate it!

Comment: @user3421870 I'm glad you find it helpful. If you later decide that it is a good answer, you can highlight it as such.